# Is it possible to get information from websites as a human?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, natural-language-processing, research

If I want to read any websites and get some information as names (or dates) on some part of the site as a human. What solution I could use in order to get these datas using deep learning or machine learning?. Is it possible?.. it is not necessary artificial inteligence? .... or maybe it might be as a part of a Phd thesis about machine learning?... If someone has a PAPER about it, could you share it with me?.

Sorry I dont know a lot about this topic.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your question is _far_ too broad: one could write a hundred books and still not really have the answer. To make your question answerable here in a reasonable amount of time, you need to make it much more focused on some specific aspect of the problem. At the moment, your question is essentially, "Natural langauge processing and information retrieval -- how do I do that?  All of it."

Comment: What do you mean by "get some information as names (or dates)"?  What do you mean by "as a human"?  I can't tell what you're trying to ask.  What are you trying to achieve?  Can you give an example?  What study have you done already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments by David and D.W. are accurate. Your question is way too broad. But to give you a hint were you might start to dive deeper into the field, here is a very general answer to your question:

Yes, it is possible. Although, the methods we have are at the moment not as good as human performance (not surprisingly—the task is very hard; side note: If you restrict the text genre and the kind of information you are looking for strongly enough (say gene interactions in biomedical texts) then it is actually possible to achieve near-expert performance).

The name of the task you are describing is [information extraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_extraction).

An excellent text book which covers elementary methods of it (as well as lots of basics in natural language processing you need to know for that) is [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131873210). There should be free pdf version around in the web as well.